# Agular same component conflict

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use two times an Angular component that (both) contains a form.
But when a `mat-radio-button` is selected, the other ones are deselected (even on the second component).
The problem happend only with the `mat-radio-group` input.

There is my component:

myform-form.component.html

```
<form #form="ngForm">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <mat-radio-group name="test" [(ngModel)]="variable">
      <mat-radio-button [value]="false">False</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button [value]="true">True</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
    <span>Selected: {{variable}}</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

myform-form.component.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'myform-form',
  templateUrl: './myform-form.component.html'
})
export class FormComponent {
  variable: boolean = true;
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <myform-form></myform-form>
    <myform-form></myform-form>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'radiatest';
}
```

I expect both of my components to be independent and I don't want the first `mat-radio-group` to be unchecked when the second one is checked.

There is the actual result where I am unable to check the upper and the below `mat-radio-group`:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is the "name" parameter. Mat-radio-group create a serie of radio buttons with the same name that this parameter.

The solution is a bit work-around. In your component.ts you declare a variable **outside** the component

```
let myformNextUniqueId = 0;
```

And add a new variable to your component "id"

```
  id:number;
  constructor(){
    this.id=myformNextUniqueId++;
  }
```

Then use this variable to give the name

```
<mat-radio-group  [name]="'test'+id" [(ngModel)]="variable">
 ...
</mat-radio-group>
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-znltyj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform.component.ts)

**Update** Another option is make your component it's neccesary an attribute name

Your constructor like

```
constructor(@Optional() @Attribute('name') public name:string){
    if (!name)
      throw new Error("The name attribute it's neccessary")
}
```

And you write

```
<mat-radio-group  [name]="name || 'fool'" [(ngModel)]="variable">
 ...
</mat-radio-group>
```

Obviously your app should be like

```
<myform-form name="one"></myform-form>
<myform-form name="two"></myform-form>
```

Comment: And could it be considered as an Angular bug ? As Angular do not encapsulate the `mat-radio-group` in its parent component to prevent this type of conflict ?

And, as you know, does something similar could append with other material components ?

Comment: @RedHeadEmile, For me is a bug of mat-radio-group. In the [github](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/25d9217fd19cdc404ad5370975afe36fe4a14ce7/src/material/radio/radio.ts#L251) they should add the `nextUniqueId` to the radios. NOTE: Sincerly it's the first time I find this problem and I feel that the only chance to happen is when we create a input type radio and use "name" attribute.

Comment: It's not an angular material bug, they use native radio buttons under the hood, and they work like that. It's not their responsibility to use unique names.